# How to connect flex4 with Symfony 2 for amf calls

Tags: apache-flex, symfony, amf

I have to use flex 4 for the front end and php with Symfony 2 as backend. I want to use amf to call remote methods on the php. I have known that Symfony 2 does not have plugin for amf communications with Flex. In this case how can I connect them? or I have to use httpservice/webservices which is slow in performance.

Comment: I think you should look at this : http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/
And the symphony plugin: http://raw.trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/sfAmfphpPlugin If you also want an amfphp tutorial:
http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow/using-amfphp-with-as3-and-codeignitor/ Good luck!

Comment: I know about using amf bundles , but is this stable? The official plugin sfamfphp is not yet available with symfony 2 , it was available with previous versions of symfony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [AMFBundle](https://github.com/tecbot/AMFBundle), which has what you need.

Comment: Is the functionality same as sfamf?

Answer (score 0):

An other solution is the Zend framework: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.amf.html